# rating directive from bootstrap-ui module if angular returns an error "Error: $compile:nonassign Non-Assignable Expression"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the rating directive  of bootstrap module for angular but when I click on a star to rate then angular trig this error

[enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24compile/nonassign?p0=2&p1=rating)

I understand that this error is produced because the value that I use in the model it's a constnatn.
Let me explain

I have this directive in nrate.html

```
<rating ng-model="rate" max="5" readonly="false" value="2"></rating>
```

and this controller

```
appControllers.controller("singleRatingController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.rate = 0;
});
```

so I'm using a variable "rate" to load the rate value

In other html page I use the same directive with the same controller and works well

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either `value` or `ng-model`, not both, depending on which UI Bootstrap version you are using.

JS for both cases:

```
appControllers.controller("singleRatingController", function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.rate = 2;
});
```

HTML - If using **0.11.0:**

```
<rating ng-model="rate" max="5" readonly="false"></rating>
```

HTML - If using **0.10.0 or below:**

```
<rating value="rate" max="5" readonly="false"></rating>
```

Comment: Certainly the problem was caused because i used the 0.9.0 vesrion and use ng-model directive. Using value instead of ng-model solve the problem.  Thanks